# creating a dictionary with two lists when a key should have two values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

hi I have two lists,

```
list1
['PO', 'NA', 'PO']

list2
['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']
```

Iam trying to get a dictionary using this two lists
I tried, `my_dict=dict(zip(list1,list2))`
it gives,

```
 {'NA': 'Not Available', 'PO': 'Post area'}
```

but my expected output is,

```
 {'NA': 'Not Available', 'PO': ['Post area','Post Office']}
```

pls help

Comment: `zip` won't do that for you - you'll need to just write the code to do that yourself.

Comment: I don't think there is any short cut here. You may have to iterate over the keys and values and if the key gets repeated add a new entry to the list corresponding to its value.

Comment: Why do you need `list1` ? and `''Post area''` shouldn't be `'PA'` ?

Comment: Start with `{x.split()[0][0] + x.split()[1][0] : x for x in ['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post Area']}` and modify it by your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two method :

> First method using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1=['PO', 'NA', 'PO']

list2=['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']

final_dict = defaultdict(list)

[final_dict[item[0]].append(item[1]) for item in zip(list1,list2)]
print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'PO': ['Post Office', 'Post area'], 'NA': ['Not Available']})
```

> Second method :

Let's solve your issue in two step:

> First zip the both list:

```
list1=['PO', 'NA', 'PO']

list2=['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']

zip_list=[item for item in zip(list1,list2)]
```

> Now check if zip tuple first element is in dict or not if it is then
>   use this awesome pattern :

```
final_dict={}
    for item in zip_list:
        if item[0] not in final_dict:
            final_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
        else:
            final_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

> Full code:

```
list1=['PO', 'NA', 'PO']

list2=['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']

zip_list=[item for item in zip(list1,list2)]
final_dict={}
for item in zip_list:
    if item[0] not in final_dict:
        final_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
    else:
        final_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(final_dict)
```

output:

```
{'NA': ['Not Available'], 'PO': ['Post Office', 'Post area']}
```

Comment: the value of key 'NA' should not be a list

Comment: @KobeNein if the value will not be a list then in `else` condition you will get an error. check the logic first.

Comment: his expected is a str obj 'Not Available' not a list ['Not Available']

Comment: @KobeNein that was just an expected output not code output , He accepted the answer it means he have no issue with that output. Otherside you can just add one more line code and you will get what you want.That is not a big issue.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul If we shuffle the value of list2 then out is not correct  in your first method.

Comment: @GauravInno i agree but that is not anything said by OP , May be he have created list like that so it will not be an issue for him.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own custom dict class using dict

```
class ListDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d={}):
        if isinstance(d, zip):
            for i, v in enumerate(d):
                self.__setattr__(v[0], v[1])
        else:
            self.update(d)

    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        if key in self:
            if not isinstance(self[key], list):
                self[key] = [self[key]]
            self[key].append(val)
        else:
            self[key] = val


list1 = ['PO', 'NA', 'PO']
list2 = ['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']
my_dict = ListDict(zip(list1, list2))
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'PO': ['Post Office', 'Post area'], 'NA': 'Not Available'}
```

Comment: Really cool approach! Some notes - 1) you don't need `enumerate` since you don't use index `i` anywhere, 2) you don't need `temp` variable - you can use `self[key] = [self[key]]` instead

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I just write what pops up in mind without thinking much about it. I'll edit as you suggested. The reason I enumerated because zip is not subscriptable like d[i]

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want because it gives you lists for single abbreviations, but it gives an output very similar to what you're looking for.
I hope it helps.

```
list1 = ['PO', 'NA', 'PO']
list2 = ['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']

my_dict = {}

for abbrev,value in zip(list1,list2):
    if abbrev in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[abbrev] += [value]
    else:
        my_dict[abbrev] = [value]
```

edit: For the sake of completeness, the code below will NOT create lists for single items and will function ok with large lists of items with many multiple matches.

```
list1 = ['PO', 'NA', 'PO']
list2 = ['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']

my_dict = {}

for abbrev,value in zip(list1,list2):
    if abbrev in my_dict.keys():
        if isinstance(my_dict[abbrev],str):
            my_dict[abbrev] = [my_dict[abbrev]]
        my_dict[abbrev] += [value]
    else:
        my_dict[abbrev] = value

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: the value of key 'NA' should not be a list

Comment: I've added a second half to my answer that covers that situation if required.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['PO', 'NA', 'PO']
list2 = ['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area']

my_dict = dict()
for key,value in zip(list1,list2):
    if key not in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] = value
    else:
        my_dict[key] = [my_dict[key]]
        my_dict[key].append(value)

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be usefull for you also.

```
list1 = ['PO', 'NA', 'PO', 'TCS', 'TCS']
list2 = ['Post Office', 'Not Available', 'Post area', 'Track Complaint Status', 'Tata Consultancy Service', 'Tata Consultancy Service']

output_dict = {}

for index, value in enumerate(list1):
     if not value in output_dict:
          output_dict.update({value:list2[index]})
     else:
          temp_list = [list2[index]]
          temp_list.append(output_dict[value])
          output_dict.update({value:temp_list})
 print(output_dict)
```

**output :-** {'NA': 'Not Available', 'PO': ['Post area', 'Post Office'], 'TCS': ['Tata Consultancy Service', 'Tata Consultancy Service']}

In this program no matter duplicate values in list2 and length too. You can modify this code according your exact problem.